# Python - Iterate through pages with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I use BeautifulSoup4 to scrape data from a few webpages. For example in below case, the url is https://wadsfred.aliexpress.com/store/425826/search/1.html, and there are 96 pages. My problem is that the script throws me an error after several pages. Usually, when the code reaches page 15-20. The error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in 
    if next_page.text != 'Next':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
import requests
import os
import csv
from itertools import count
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

os.chdir('C:\MyFolder')
page_nr = 1
price = []
min_order = []
prod_name = []

for page_number in count(start = 1):
    url = 
'https://wadsfred.aliexpress.com/store/425826/search/{}'.format(page_nr) + 
'.html'
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    for div_b in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'cost'}):
        price.append(div_b.text)

    for min_or in soup.find_all('span', {'class':'min-order'}):
        min_order.append(min_or.text)

    for pr_name in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'detail'}):
        for pr_h in pr_name.find_all('h3'):
            for pr_title in pr_h.find_all('a'):
                prod_name_s = (pr_title.get('title').strip())
                prod_name.append(prod_name_s[:120])

    print(len(prod_name))
    page_nr = page_nr + 1
    next_page = soup.find('a', {'class':'ui-pagination-next'})
    if next_page.text != 'Next':
      break
```

Comment: you should add a time.sleep(5) after each request to avoid a ban (nothing to do with your problem). and could you try ti print the other infos you add before on this page (to see if they are not null)

Comment: I think we are on the right track, but the 5 sec didn't solve the problem. After a few runs (between 5-15), it gave me the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: so the problem is not that yo can't got through all the pages but that you can't rerun the code multiple time? (to be honest the URL you are requesting is classifying you as a bot so they'll track you and if you overload their server, they'll ban you. you should try to hide yourself a bit better(look at selenium))

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestion! I suppose it is time to learn some Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It redirected to login page, Add user-agent to your request

```
heads = {"User-Agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0......'}
for page_number in count(start = 1):
    .....
    response = requests.get(url, headers=heads)
```

even better use `requests.session()` to create persistent session (cookies)

Comment: Thanks, that was a jedi stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the 'a' tag with class 'ui-pagination-next' is not present in some pages.
You can skip that check when you already know there are 96 pages in all. And put the scraping block in try catch to skip errors in some pages.

Comment: That was a good one, thanks, the AttributeError is trapped, but the problem still exists, because after a few runs, it doesn't retrieve any more data. Let's says the prod_name list contains 216 elements, and it doesn't increase, only the number of the pages change. 
216
https://www.aliexpress.com/store/910054/search/78.html
216
https://www.aliexpress.com/store/910054/search/79.html
216
https://www.aliexpress.com/store/910054/search/80.html